# check the database and insert if data not exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have the table 'role' with fields user_id and role_id.I have get the new value from the another query 154,516 from the for loop.I want to check 154 is in the role table user_id if not exit insert the new field or if exist update the field.In my case update the role_id for the user_id '154' and insert the new row for '516'.

```
role //table
user_id   role_id
210        1
125        2
310        1
154        1


foreach($heads as $head){
          $first_count=$first_count+1;
            $roleMappingObject = new role_mapping();
            $roleMappingObject->user_id = $head->user_id;
            $roleMappingObject->role_id = 1;
            $roleMappingObject->save (); //this will insert the new row for both 154 and 516 but I want to update '154'
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case it seems like your **role_id** is not a foreign key, if that's the case you can just use the eloquent functions [firstOrCreate/ firstOrNew](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#other-creation-methods)

The **firstOrCreate** will search for instance with given data and return that instance or will save that instance.

The **firstOrNew** will find and return or create instance but doesn't save it in database as you will have to do it by calling save() method.

But if your role_id is foreign key i.e. key id of other table than you should prefer it in way defined in laravel's documentation for [many to many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) changing your **role** table to **role_user** and creating relation between users and roles table. In that way you will be able to use the methods attach / detach.

Answer (score 0):

Set a many to many relation between your users and roles

User Model

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_user');
}
```

Role Model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_user');
}
```

And then

```
$user->roles()->attach($roleId));
```